# Why is my Dishwasher making a loud popping sound when draining/switching cycles?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dishwasher, garbage-disposal

I recently replaced my kitchen floors and, in the process, noticed my dishwasher was wired very poorly and was not in a box. A friend of mine put everything in a box the way it was wired before but now it makes a loud popping noise any time it changes cycles/drains.  Also, when we turned off the breaker for it, it was mislabeled at the breaker box.  The 'dishwasher' switch did nothing but when we turned off the 'garbage disposal' switch, it killed power to the dishwasher which makes me think the dishwasher was wired to the garbage disposal wires by the previous owner.  We don't have a garbage disposal.  My questions is why is it making a loud popping sound? [image: The new box installed].[image: Possible old wires used for the dishwasher?]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a _Question_ & Answer forum. Do you have an actual question or are you just sharing?

Comment: I was asking why the dishwasher was making the popping sound.  I have updated my post in the form of a question.